# how to obtain cabal default config location

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

Is there a way to obtain the default cabal config directory, i.e. the path you would specify in `ghc-pkg.exe init {path}`?

I wanted it in a script to automatically remove that folder for repairing/re-installing ghc.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the `~/.cabal/config` file?

Comment: Thanks. I am using msys/mingw, and I checked there is no ~/.cabal folder. However, there is '/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/ting/Application\ Data/cabal/config' (I am using Windows XP). My question is whether there is a platform independent way to find this location.

Comment: The last line of `cabal help` displays the path to the default config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @user2407038's comments, I obtained the location of the cabal config location with

```
cabal help | tail -n1
```

and removed the folder using

```
rm -rf `cabal help | tail -n1 | xargs dirname`
```